# Why am I getting build errors from scintillawrappers demo project?

Tags: scintilla, scilexer.dll

`CScintillaCtrl`, `CScintillaView` & `CScintillaDoc` `v1.28` downloaded and I opened it in VS 2005 but when I tried to build it I get more than 100 errors all pertaining to scintilla functions; example:

`scintillactrl.cpp(1129)` : `error C2065: 'SCI_MARKERSETBACKSELECTED : undeclared identifier ;`

why are some identifiers unrecognized but others like `SCI_ADDTEXT` are ?